# How to load data into javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following Javascript/jquery code. How can i set the value of data into the graph.

Javascript:

```
$('#graphmodal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var a = $(event.relatedTarget); 

    var data_int = a.data('data_int'); 
    var modal2 = $(this);

    var ctx = document.getElementById('chartBartest').getContext('2d');
    new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'],
            datasets: [{
                data: [data_int]
            }]
    });
})
```

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-link" href='#'            
   data-data_int="648, 504, 488, 504, 488, 504, 504, 455, 504, 488, 504, 488"
   data-toggle="modal" 
  data-target="#graphmodal">
  Interest Trends
</a>
```

Comment: It seems there is a missing curly bracket in your `new Chart`, the data object is not closed. Is this a copy paste mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your string to an array and use that for data as below:

```
$('#graphmodal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var a = $(event.relatedTarget); 

    var data_int = a.data('data_int').split(","); 
    var modal2 = $(this);

    var ctx = document.getElementById('chartBartest').getContext('2d');
    new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'],
            datasets: [{
                data: data_int
            }]
    });
})
```

Hope it helps you.